# Extract filename from Content-Disposition header with special characters

Tags: php, regex, header

I need to extract the filename (with extension) from a Content-Disposition header. I have used this regex before:

```
/.*filename=[\'\"]?([^\'\"]+)/
```

but it doesn't work with filenames like this one:

> EXAMPLE- I'm ößä.dat

So I am looking for an regex which can handle such a filename

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iZ7oJ0/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture group `([^\'\"]+)` contains a negated character class that doesn't allow one quote since you have one quote in `I'm`.

If you remove the one quote it will work :

```
/.*filename=[\'\"]?([^\"]+)/
```

See Demo  https://regex101.com/r/pY9mR4/1

Also for matching the quotation around the file name it's better to use a group reference at the end of regex:

```
/.*filename=([\'\"]?)([^\"]+)\1/
```

https://regex101.com/r/pY9mR4/2